# aws_autoscaling_group and count.index in user_data template_file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have `template_file` containing `user_data` for `launch_template` backing and ASG.

What I want to achieve is to use one element from array variable in each ASG instance

```
variable "my_array_var" {
  type = "list"
  default = [ "one", "two" ]
}

data "template_file" "node-user-data" {
  count = "${length(var.my_array_var)}"
  template = <<EOF
#cloud-config
runcmd:
  - [ my-command, ${element(var.my_array_var, count.index)} ]
EOF
}

resource "aws_launch_template" "node-lt" {
  name = "node-lt"
  image_id = "${var.instance_ami}"
  instance_type = "${var.instance_type_node}"

  user_data = "${base64encode(data.template_file.node-user-data.rendered)}"
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "node-asg" {
  name = "node-asg"
  desired_capacity = 2
  max_size = 2
  min_size = 2

  launch_template {
    id = "${aws_launch_template.node-lt.id}"
    version = "$$Latest"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do that with terraform?

Comment: Typically the instances in an ASG will leverage the same userdata, whats the use case?

Comment: I'm building Selenium cluster and wanted instances in same ASG to have different browser configurations - say one with chrome, another with firefox, etc.

Comment: I'd make them separate or each instance has all configuration capabilities.

Comment: Actually I went all on each approach. Thanks for confirming my thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

Use the following call in your cloud-init script:

```
host_index=$(wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/ami-launch-index)
```

Comment: Good hint! Well